# How to check 2 different types of things using ===?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to check whether the value in an input box is equal to a variable. When I use ===, it returns false but when I use ==, it returns true, provided both are equal.

```
<input id="g1"></input> <button id="b" onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
function myFunction() {
var d1;
d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
if( document.getElementById("g1").value ==  d1) {
document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = "Correct";
}
```

Comment: the textbox value is a type of `String` and you're comparing it to a type of `number` `===` will return `false` if the types don't match

Comment: `===` is used for strict checking.  Why would you want to defeat that purpose?

Comment: Because the value inside the input box is string, use parseInt() to convert it to integer

Comment: if you console.log both you will realise they are not equal - one is number, another is string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because JavaScript `==` can compare numeric strings to numbers whereas `===` does not.

Similarly the "value" property your using returns a string that you're comparing to an integer. You'll need to use `parseInt` to convert the value first.

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("g1").value) ===  d1
```

A few things to consider with `parseInt`:

- `parseInt` returns `NaN` when you try to convert non-number strings (i.e. converting `'bogus'` returns `NaN`.
- It will convert decimals into integers by dropping the decimals. So `parseInt('2.1') == 2 // => true`.

Honestly, given your use case, it's appropriate to use `==`, but I'd add a comment explaining why it's being used.

Answer (score 1):

=== means both value has to be equals but have same type of data in it aswell where == means they only needs to be equal. so for example if d1 is a string holding value 2 and g1 is an integer also holding value 2 using === would not work and will return false as both data is different even though they have same syntax.

```
<input id="g1"></input> <button id="b" onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
function myFunction() {
var d1 = 0;
d1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
if( paseint(document.getElementById("g1").value) ===  d1) {
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = "Correct";
 }
```

Comment: The way the code is its fine, but if you want to use === then make sure to convert both data to integer.

Comment: As the answer above parseInt(document.getElementById("g1").value) ===  d1

Answer (score 0):

== is the equality operator
=== is an identity operator

For example true==1 is true because true is converted to 1 and then it's compared. However, true===1 is false. This is because it does not do type coercion.

That aside, in your case I think you want to try casting your value to an integer and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string5 = '5'
var numb5 = 5
if (string5 == numb5) will  return true
if (string5 === numb5) will  return false
```

second variant also compares type, because string is not same type as number it is false.